# Im getting ROOM NO for each column value.How could i get different column value in front of each column

Tags: python

I m getting ROOM NO for all column values. I want to display different columns values for each column. how could i do that please help.
Here is my code

```
    def view():
         c.execute('select * from seat_allocation')
         for row in c.fetchone():
             print(row)
             tree insert("", tk.END, values=row, text="ROOM NO")
         c.close()
```

There are 7 columns ROOM NO, LINE NO, BENCH NO, REGISTRATION NO, PAPER CODE, EXAM DATE, INVIGILATOR NAME. values are 16, 1, B2, 16PJ, CORE-5, 02-05-19, R. K respectively of 1st row of table seat_allocation. Total rows are 50. I m displaying one row(information of student) one time.

Comment: can you provide more details about the content of the table your are querying?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer and now I want to share it so that it might help anyone.

```
    def p():
        global screen1

        screen1 = Tk()
        screen1.title("MY HALL")

        screen1.geometry("1500x800")
        screen1.configure(bg='yellow')

        tree = ttk.Treeview(screen1, selectmode='browse')

        conn = sqlite3.connect('TABLE.DB')
        c = conn.cursor()

        def view_my_hall():
            c.execute("SELECT * FROM Seat_Allocation ")
            for row in c.fetchall():

                ROOM_NAME =        row[0]
                LINE_NO =          row[1]
                BENCH_NO =         row[2]
                REGISTRATION_NO =  row[3]
                PAPER_CODE =       row[4]
                EXAM_DATE =        row[5]
                INVIGILATOR_NAME = row[6]

                tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row[0], text="ROOM NAME/ROOM NO")
                tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row[1], text="LINE NO")
                tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row[2], text="BENCH NO")
                tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row[3], text="REGISTRATION NO")    
                tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row[4], text="PAPER CODE")
                tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row[5], text="EXAM DATE")
                tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row[6], text="INVIGILATOR NAME") 
                break

            conn.commit()

        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure('Treeview', rowheight=48)
        tree = ttk.Treeview(screen1, column=("column1","column2","column3"))

        tree.heading("#1", text="VIEW")
        tree.heading("#2", text="YOUR")
        tree.heading("#3", text="HALL")
        tree.column("#1", width=30, minwidth=0)
        tree.column("#2", width=30, minwidth=0)
        tree.column("#3", width=30, minwidth=0)

        button1 = Button(screen1, text="VIEW", command=view_my_hall, anchor='center', bg='blue', fg='white', width=10)
        button1.pack()
        button2 = Button(screen1, text="BACK", command=screen16.destroy, anchor='center', bg='blue', fg='white', width=10)
        button2.pack()

        tree.pack()

        screen1.mainloop()
```